# Is there an upgrade guide from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I've got a webpage written in L3 and I feel that it's on time to move it forward to L4. So I'm searching for a howto-guide telling me the porting process. In which folders my old files belonges now into and which parts of code have to be rewritten, syntax changes and so on.

Answer (score 7):

James Gordon wrote a nice blog post detailing the various sections that would need to be changed.

[Upgrading from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4](http://yetanotherprogrammingblog.com/content/upgrading-from-laravel-3-to-laravel-4)

> It took roughly three full days of effort (lets call that 24 hours) to
>   convert the application from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4. Not including
>   app/config, app/lang, app/tests or any other Laravel code that exists
>   in the project structure, both projects consisted of a little over
>   2,500 lines of code. The exact line counts for the original project
>   are as follows:
>
> Folder    LOC controllers 540 helpers 183 models  927 tasks   384 views   476
>   Total 2,510

Answer (score 3):

[Official changelog](http://wiki.laravel.io/Changelog_%28Laravel_4%29) should help you.

Also don't forget to change your method names. All `snake_case` method names are converted to `camelCase`.

Edit: folder names are almost same. `application` folder became `app`, model, view and controllers' folders' paths are still same under the app folder. Migrations are now in `app/database/migrations` folder.

Routing has changed a bit. the `:num`, `:all` etc is dropped, now you can name them anything, and set their rules with regex.

E.g: This:

```
Route::get('my/method/(:num)', array('as' => 'name', 'uses' => 'controller@method'));
```

became like this:

```
Route::get('my/method/{id}', array('as' => 'name', 'uses' => 'yourController@yourMethod'))->where('id','[0-9]+');
```

(`id` is not a must, you can name it anything.)

```
Route::get('my/method/{foo}', array('as' => 'name', 'uses' => 'yourController@yourMethod'))->where('foo','[0-9]+');
```

For the filters, you can now use `app/filters.php` instead of putting them into your `routes.php`.